# PHPexcel doesn't read cell value, but Excel reads the proper cell value

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm having weird issues when trying to get calculated value of one cell in one worksheet.
The thing is, PHPExcel writer does the good job and when I open generate file with excel, that cell contains for egg. 1.05,   but when trying to read that same cell with PHPexcel again, I get  2.75.

Anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Can you please share some code here?

Comment: [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: So what should the result of the formula be? What is the formula? Does it contain any cyclic references? It's very difficult to help when you provide an inadequate description of your problem

Comment: There have been some fixes to shared formulae in the latest develop branch on github, please try with that version

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. It turns out that formulas are a bit loose, even Excel warns me about inconsistent values. 

I could send example xlsx for someone to take a look at it, together with related code - but it's not urgent anymore.